# Using the stop in a loop with conditionals

Tags: javascript

Hello there I'm finding it difficult to understand some basic JavaScript

I have written a loop that counts down from 10 to 0 and I'm using console.log to print that value to the console. Inside the loop an `if` statement is used to check if the number is 0, if it is then console.log prints "Blast Off!" instead of a number.

Here is my working code:

```
for (i=10; i>=0; i--;) 
{
if (i === 0)    
    {
    console.log("Blast Off!");
    }
else 
    {
    console.log(i);
    }
}
```

However what I'm desperately trying to understand the is the stop of the `for` loop which is:

```
i>=0;
```

Is this effectively saying if `i` is greater than or equal to zero then progress through the loop decrementing `i` each time, then stop when zero is reached?

Conversely when I change the `for` loop code to what is shown below, is this effectively saying if `i` is less than or equal to zero then progress through the loop decrementing `i` each time until zero is reached?

What is the reason for the loop not printing, if the stop is changed? Is this because `i` **never** holds a value that is less than or equal to zero, meaning the loop will not run?

```
 i<=0;
```

Any help clearing this up for me would be appreciated massively.

Comment: for (i=10; i>=0; i--)  - you are missing a ; at i--. You do realise that console.log() will only show in something like firebug or chrome developer tools and wont print to the screen?

Comment: Thank you for your observation of the missing ; and yes I am currently using firebug to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding sounds correct. When the `for` statement is executed, the first expression assigns a value to `i` (in this case, `10`). The second expression is a comparison. It will evaluate to `true` if `i` is greater than or equal to `0` (which it is, as we just set it to 10). Because the condition evaluates to `true`, the loop body is executed. After that, the third expression runs, decrementing the value of `i`, and that process is repeated until the condition evaluates to `false` (when `i` reaches 0).

By changing the condition to `i <= 0`, it will evaluate to `false` the first time around, so the loop body will never execute.

The exact behaviour is detailed in the ECMAScript specification, in the section on "[the `for` statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.3)".

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a set of stairs, 10 steps.

```
--
  | i = 10
   --
     | i = 9
      --
        | i = 8
         --
           | i = 7
            --
              | i = 6
               --
                 | i = 5
                  --
                    | i = 4
                     --
                       | i = 3
                        --
                          | i = 2
                           --
                             | i = 1
                              --
                                | i = 0
```

Imagine you are climbing down the stairs, in your head, you subconsciously think: "Until I get down to the bottom-most step, I'll keep stepping down".

Similar to the for loop:

`for (i=10; i >= 0; i--)`

This says, I start from the top-most, the 10th step as depicted in the image, then you climb down one step each time (or iteration) `i--`, then everytime after you step down, you check, "Am I at the bottom of the stairs already? No? Keep going", that's when you check `i >= 0`

Hope that helps you out of your desperation ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is the semicolon extra in the loop:

this is your code:

```
for (i=10; i>=0; i--;)
```

try this:

```
for (i=10; i>=0; i--)
```

Maybe that's the reason for the loop is not printing.

Answer (score 1):

`for (i=10; i>=0; i--)` means this:

1. start with `i=10`
2. if not `i>=0` then execute. This is the "stop" condition.
3. after each loop do: `i = i-1`

On this example you won't enter the loop because the repeat condition fails.

Answer (score 1):

Hello ok first "i=10" and

```
i>=0
```

is the condition for the loop. So everytime the `i` is greater or equal to zero the loop is returning continueing. Since you are using `i--` so when `i` becomes negative less then zero the loop will stop.

if you use

```
i<=0
```

the condition for the loop is false so it won't enter the loop to execute the code inside bracket

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you were to change

```
for (i=10; i>=0; i--)
```

to

```
for (i=10; i<=0; i--)
```

the first condition check is false, as i is not smaller or equal to 0, so it will not eter the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is checked before entering the block, but after the incrementation. The incrementation is skipped the first interation. The first time the condition is not met, the whole loop will stop completely.

So if you use i<=0, the condition is not met, and the for will stop.
If you want to skip the zero, you should have the condition i>0.

Answer (score 0):

You understand correctly, the i>=0 in your for loop tells to run the loop as long as i is greater than or equal to 0.

The i-- decrements the value of i on each iteration of the loop.